# I don't want to add index.jsx page in my pages folder

Tags: next.js, url-routing

I'm able to redirect desire page when run the project but because I haven't added index.jsx page inside pages folder at first I'm getting error page which says  -

[image]

But then it take me to desire route which I mentioned in app.js page.

I don't want user to show error page and directly take it to mentioned routing path(for example - /home).

How to achieve this?

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you use react-router, you can use these codes to redirect the error page to the specified page（eg, shopping.jsx）, as follows

```js
import React from "react";
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";

let router = {};

router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "admin/",
    element: <Admin />
  },
  {
    path: "register/",
    element: <Register />,
  },
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Login />,
    // this element in case something went wrong
    errorElement: <App/>
  },
]);


const Router = <RouterProvider router={router} />;

export default Router;
```